# Share an Ionic Framework app with users for testing on real devices

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I have made an Ionic Framework 4 app and have tested on my laptop and own phone using localhost but now want to get a few users to test it on their devices. I don't want to put it on any app stores as it's for my uni final project so isn't good enough for that. From what I have read there is no way to test on iOS devices without uploading to the App Store, but I have read testing on Android is easier.

Please could you advise me on how to go about deploying the app for users to test?

Thanks!

Comment: for android you can build the app locally using the ionic cordova build command and send the apk to your users for testing https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-build

Comment: @Bart Thank you! Silly question but what is the best way to then send the apk file to the users?

Comment: @CDummy If it's only for a small university project why not upload it to some cloud service (my university has its own for things like that) and share the link to it via email or if it's really small just send it directly as an email attachment.

Comment: @FabianN. oh cool thank you! I didn't realise you could just email attach it haha! Thanks so much :)

Comment: Yes it's a really simple process, the only extra step will be on install - there will be a security message to enable install from unknown sources (i.e. the app has come from somewhere that isn't google play)

Answer (score 1):

I can see some discussion in the comments above about just sideloading this.

That's a good, simple option, but it does require your testers to reduce their security settings to allow loading of apps from non-Google sources.

This depends on your users if this is a responsible thing to ask them. If you are dealing with technically minded people this is ok, but if it's for casual users you need to be sure that you revert this setting afterwards, otherwise they could fall prey to a phishing scam in the future because of what you have asked them to do.

If you do choose to do it via the Google Play app store then you have options for distributing to a select group of people without ever putting it live in the public app store.

Its a $25 lifetime fee to join the app store. Then you can release on the internal testing track for up to 100 users. You just invite them via email, they enroll in your testing channel, and then they can install it safely via the app store.

Comment: There is nothing "lifetime" about it. Lifetime would imply that it is a fee a developer would pay "once in a lifetime", and that would be it, they would never again during their life need to pay said fee. Google lied to you about this. What they really meant was "one time fee until your account goes inactive after 180 days". Let me remind you, 180 days is EXTREMELY opposite of "Lifetime". A “bait and switch” is a scam to mislead developers, whereby Google advertises an appealing but ingenuine offer to sell a service that Google does not actually intend to honor (i.e. "Lifetime").